# Java Regex Group By Doesn't Work As Expected For Numbers

Tags: java, regex

I am running into an issue with Java Matchers. I may be overlooking something very small here but the following matcher does not give the expected results

```
    private static final Pattern STANDARD_NAME_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("MySampleString.*?/(?<PatternOne>.+?)/(?<PatternTwo>\\w+?)/PatternThree(?<PatternThree>\\d+?).*");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String key = "PatternThree";
        String value = "EMPTY";
        String name = "MySampleString/IRRELEVANT/IRRELEVANT/PatternThree15";
        Matcher matcher = STANDARD_NAME_PATTERN.matcher(name);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            value = matcher.group(key);
        }
        System.out.println(value);
    }
```

The following output is

```
1
```

However, I would expect it to be 15 here since we are matching the numbers with \d+
The other two patterns are matching with words... Not sure what the issue is here, if someone could provide insight.

One of the hacks I could use is

```
Pattern.compile("MySampleString.*?/(?<PatternOne>.+?)/(?<PatternTwo>\\w+?)/PatternThree(?<PatternThree>\\d\\d\\d?).*");
```

But ideally would not want to do this since it doesn't scale

Comment: If you make the quantifier non greedy `\d+?` it will match as least as possible, in this case a single digit as the following `.*` is also optional and can also match a digit. You can use `\d+` instead.

Comment: You're not understanding how regex works.  Regex is to detect known pattern, not to extract the values attached that pattern.  It found your pattern3 with digits attached, but you'll have to do a lot more work to find out what those dgits are.

Comment: Ryan, please review the following documentation to expand your knowledge around Java Regex and its use cases :) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group()

Answer (score 2):

Try this (remove last question mark):

```
MySampleString.*?/(?<PatternOne>.+?)/(?<PatternTwo>\w+?)/PatternThree(?<PatternThree>\d+).*
```

See Regex [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WMeRX7/1)